# Memcache for PHP when mysql in dedicated server

Tags: mysql, memcached, dedicated-server

I am having a dedicated server host MySQL in one server and Apache & my Drupal application in another server. But now I am confused where memcached should be installed? If its in the MySql server how do we point to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use APC on Apache server, It will be much faster than memcache because you don't need to make a tcp/ip call to connect to memcache.

Then if you still want use memcache install it on Apache server, it will be little bit faster than connecting to another machine. And it will be easier to maintain, leave mysql machine as a standalone server and run only mysql on it